# Nested SELECT + INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, nested, normalization

First table

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city_node` (
 `node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `parent_node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `lft` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set info ''left'' value',
 `rgt` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Nested set info ''right'' value',
 `depth` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Depth = 0: no parent',
 PRIMARY KEY (`node_id`),
 KEY `parent_node_id` (`parent_node_id`),
 KEY `lft` (`lft`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=26;
```

And data

```
INSERT INTO `city_node` (`node_id`, `title`, `parent_node_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `depth`) VALUES
(1, 'Great Britain', 0, 1, 20, 0),
(3, 'England', 1, 2, 9, 1),
(7, 'Scotland', 1, 16, 19, 1),
(8, 'Edinburgh', 7, 17, 18, 2),
(9, 'Wales', 1, 10, 15, 1),
(10, 'Cardiff', 9, 11, 12, 2),
(11, 'London', 3, 3, 4, 2),
(12, 'Birmingham', 3, 5, 6, 2),
(13, 'Germany', 0, 21, 26, 0),
(14, 'Stuttgart', 13, 22, 23, 1),
(15, 'Newport', 9, 13, 14, 2),
(16, 'Munich', 13, 24, 25, 1),
(17, 'Israel', 0, 27, 32, 0),
(18, 'Tel Aviv', 17, 28, 29, 1),
(19, 'Ashdod', 17, 30, 31, 1),
(20, 'USA', 0, 33, 38, 0),
(21, 'New York', 20, 34, 35, 1),
(24, 'Liverpool', 3, 7, 8, 2),
(25, 'Detroit', 20, 36, 37, 1);
```

Second table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city_node_entity` (
  `node_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `entity` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  KEY `node_id` (`node_id`,`entity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And data

```
INSERT INTO `city_node_entity` (`node_id`, `entity`) VALUES
(11, 1),
(12, 1),
(16, 1),
(19, 1);
```

I want to get node with entity 1 and its ancestors, like this

Great Britain
--England
----London
----Birmingham
Germany
--Munich
Israel
--Ashdod

So, my query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(node_ext.node_id), node_ext.*
FROM city_node_entity AS entity
LEFT JOIN city_node AS node 
    ON entity.node_id = node.node_id 
LEFT JOIN city_node AS node_ext 
    ON node_ext.lft <= node.lft AND node_ext.rgt >= node.rgt
WHERE entity.entity = 1
ORDER BY node_ext.lft
```

But explain shows 
-Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

Is there any other queries to get same result but with less [EXTRA]?

Comment: mysql doesn't support recursive queries... how many levels deep will this go?

Comment: levels deep has no limit

Comment: then this isn't possible in mysql... there is no support for recursive queries.. if I know how many levels then it is possible but only by that

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do for recursive queries is to run it with joins for each parent/child.... because your second table is the actual city name and you want to work backwards you can do it like this... just add more joins till all results are null and you will have yourself the full tree

```
SELECT node.title AS child, t2.title as parent1, t3.title as parent2, t4.title as parent3
FROM city_node_entity AS entity
LEFT JOIN city_node AS node ON entity.node_id = node.node_id 
LEFT JOIN city_node AS t2 ON t2.node_id = node.parent_node_id
LEFT JOIN city_node AS t3 ON t3.node_id = t2.parent_node_id
LEFT JOIN city_node AS t4 ON t4.node_id = t3.parent_node_id;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f86c/7)

Comment: Doesn't this rather undermine the point of working with nested sets?

Comment: @Strawberry considering MySQL has no recursive functionality this is the best you can do in only MySQL

Comment: But I thought nested sets were supposed to obviate the need for recursion - perhaps I've misunderstood the question :-(

Comment: @Strawberry actually I misread the question.... didn't notice the nested tag... not sure what the OP wants considering his query returns the depth level of each thing...